# Can't find right resources for using TFS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs

I've always used svn with tortoise svn client for the source control of my asp.net mvc projects, but now I want to try TFS.
I've my account on xxxxx.visualstudio.com and I managed to create a new solution, connect it to source control and then I checkin all the files.
Fine.. I see that all my file are on the server.
When I use another pc I connect to team foundation server, get the latest version of my project, but there's no .sln file.
What's the correct way to check out a project and have it ready to compile on a different pc?

Sorry for the dumb question, maybe I'm not searching in the right way on google.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that the code you have in your TFS will work out of the box, what I do is that I **create a second TFS workspace** (a second location for a source controlled solution on your hard drive) from within Visual Studio and I perform a Get Latest operation on that workspace (thereby downloading the files into the newly created workspace).

This will enable you to see the solution in the same state as when another team member connects to TFS for the first time and performs the Get Latest operation. Then you can work out which files did you forget to add to source control, broken library references, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Download the TFS 2012 Power Tools here:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f

They will add a windows context menu option called "Team Foundation Server" that you can use just like Tortoise SVN. Let's you add, remove, and ignore files on your workspace folder with more ease, and you don't need to have visual studio open for it to work.

Hope that helps!